# Can not open a particular web site, only javascript code is on the screen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to open www.exoplatform.com with Chrome Version 39.0.2171.71 m. 
All I get on the screen is Javascript code. Tried to open with different browser, the same story.

Tried to open with other notebooks, works perfectly fine.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Some errors from chrome console:

```
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
   (index):2244 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    all.js:61 Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. 

    Refused to load the script 'https://www.best-deals-products.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?   
   dlsource=hdrykzc' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
   "script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' https://*.gstatic.com
```

It sounds really weird.

I can open any other web sites, but just this one. 
For example I can open: 
       http://blog.exoplatform.com/en/

I tried to pause Adblock nothing changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Works fine for me on Version 39.0.2171.71 m. Looks like a local security policy is in place, preventing a required script from loading, hence the issues on rendering the page.

Comment: Can you check your Network Tab in the Chrome Debugger tool and see which call is getting failed.

Comment: I have checked Network tab. but do not see any failure there.

Comment: In case you haven't heard http://superuser.com/questions/880062/what-is-the-superfish-ssl-certificate-and-where-did-it-originate

Answer (score 9):

I had this exact problem today with a new laptop I bought (Lenovo y50... is your machine a lenovo by chance?)

Anyways, the problem for me was caused by what is essentially adware injecting that script into ANY page you go to. You only see this error when trying to access a web app, because chrome has stricter security policies for those.

If you google about best-deals-products.com you'll find information about how to remove the adware, most of which is pretty unhelpful. Here is what did it for me though:

go to control panel -> add and remove programs
look for "Visual Discovery" by Superfish Inc.
uninstall that.
reboot, and revisit that page.

Comment: Hi, yes, mine is also lenovo. I delete many programs I installed, and then it disappeared. but I still feel adware is still there, since sometime it opens some game pages automatically.

Comment: Note that you should [also remove the certificate](https://filippo.io/Badfish/removing.html).

Answer (score 0):

[It has been revealed](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/02/lenovo-pcs-ship-with-man-in-the-middle-adware-that-breaks-https-connections/) that many of the Lenovo computers are shipped with a software called "Superfish" which performs man-in-the-middle attack on all HTTP, and even secure HTTPS request using a self-signed SSL certificate.

Furthermore, thanks to the ignorance of the company behind it, [the private key included has already been extracted](http://blog.erratasec.com/2015/02/extracting-superfish-certificate.html), ready to be used in public to intercept any HTTPS traffic coming from a Lenovo computer.

That means, even for banking or transactions, any attacker can read the supposedly secure content by sniffing your Wi-Fi signal. This is a very hazardous situation.

You can check out if you're vulnerable [here](https://filippo.io/Badfish). Lenovo issued an instruction to remove the software and the certificate [here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/product_security/superfish_uninstall).